# Why does this unchanged variable change values within the same function? (Is it because of caching?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, caching

I have a function that gets called within `$(document).ready()`. You'll notice I put two debugging statements in the function. The first debug statement gets the value of `dragAndDropEnabled` at the top of the function. The second statement gets the value of `dragAndDropEnabled` within the "inner" property of a JSON, which you'll see if you scroll down.

When I open the web page, I get conflicting values for `dragAndDropEnabled`. The first debug statement gives `Line 41: Update NOT permitted`. But the second debug statement gives `Line 61: Update permitted`.

Why does the variable `dragAndDropEnabled` assume two different values in the same function while going unchanged throughout the whole function?

This only happens when I change user permissions and then re-open my web page. This leads me to think that the `extraSettings` JSON is being **cached**, whereas the function `initialiseTree` is not cached. Thus the first debug statement gives the uncached value of `dragAndDropEnabled`, whereas the second debug statement gives the cached value of a JSON.

That's my best guess as to what's happening. Is my guess correct (i.e. cached vs. uncached)? If so, how do I correct this behavior? If not, what's going on?

```
var initialiseTree = function(dragAndDropEnabled) {

    $('#debugInfo').append("Line 41: " + (dragAndDropEnabled ? "Update permitted<br/>" : "Update NOT permitted<br/>"));

    var extraSettings = {
        edit: {

            drag: {

                inner: function(treeId, treeNodes, targetNode) {

                    $('#debugInfo').append("Line 61: " + (dragAndDropEnabled ? "Update permitted<br/>" : "Update NOT permitted<br/>"));

                    if (!dragAndDropEnabled)
                        return false;

                    // rest of code omitted
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.extend(true, settings, extraSettings);

    zTree = $.fn.zTree.init($('#treeDiv'), settings, [rootNode]);
}
```

Comment: What is `showTree`? There is not enough context to judge your guess.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir showTree initialises an instance of zTree, which is a jQuery plugin. The anonymous function mapping to the "inner" property gets called when a user tries to drag and drop a folder within zTree.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir My question boils down to: can a JSON within a function be cached without the function itself being cached, resulting in a conflict of values if the same variable is referenced within the function and the JSON?

Comment: And does it have access to the same `config` object? Where does `config` object get defined anyway?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The config object gets defined before documentReady. It's in the scope of the initialiseTree() function.

Comment: There is no caching here. Caching doesn't work like that. The value is getting changed somewhere between the two calls, in the code that isn't included in the question.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I changed it to a local variable `dragAndDropEnabled` and I still get the same behavior. The variable clearly isn't being changed anywhere since it's local to the function and there's no hidden code that changes it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It does seem like the anonymous function mapping to `inner` is getting cached...

Comment: See? That's just proofs that there is no caching going on. Can you post the entire code? Probably not in the question, maybe in a jsFiddle or the like and add the link to the question please.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I posted a little more code. I think it might have to do with the $.extend statement. Perhaps it's remembering the value it was set to before and not overwriting...

Comment: Not enough context.

Comment: I'm 100% confident, that the code you've presented in the question can not possible, in any way, behave the way you've described - `dragAndDropEnabled` is never altered in the code you've shown, therefore it can never change